# Creating Directory in Shell Causes Last Folder to have Extra "\r"

Tags: shell

I'm writing a basic shell script that creates directories and changes directories to that folder to write in it.

Right now I have the following:

```
mkdir -p "Home/first/second/third"
cd "Home/first/second/third"
```

This produces undesired results as the file structure looks as follows:

```
 - Home
   - first
   - second
   - third\r
```

I'm looking to get rid of the `\r` on the `third\r` but am unsure why it is doing so. I've tried a ton of different variations and can't seem to figure out what the issue is with adding that extra `\r`

Comment: What OS and shell are you using?

Comment: @Klox I'm ssh'd using PuTTY. Not my actual machine. I believe what I'm connected to is just a Linux environment.

Comment: You have saved your script with Windows line endings (CR-LF) rather than Unix (LF only).  What editor are you using?  It quite possibly has an option for specifying the line endings that files are saved with.

Comment: @jasonharper I've created and modified the script on Windows before transferring it to the Linux server where I execute it. I use Sublime to modify the script

Comment: It [sounds like](https://superuser.com/a/654497/92353) PuTTY has a "Implicit CR in every LF" option that you could disable. How are you seeing the \r? Could it be that the \r is not part of the directory name but it is being appended as part of the communications with the Linux machine? IT would help to know how PuTTY is configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit to @Klox for figuring this out.

> Files edited on a Windows computer end in \r\n, while files edited on Linux computers end in \n.

Therefore, despite the code being compiled on Linux, it still ends created files with `\r\n`, causing the last directory created in a `mkdir` to end with `\r`. In order to remove this `\r`, **files must be written in the linux environment**.

Comment: @Klox You were right. I appreciate your help. If you wish to write an answer, I can mark it as correct. If not, I'll just mark this one as correct so there is an answer to this question

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that's the exact script?

Because the mkdir -p "Home/first/second/third" should and does create a structure like.

```
Home
  - first
    - second
      - third
```

You do need to clarify what OS and shell you are using.

Did you create the file on the host or copy it to the host from a windows machine?

-EDIT
Use

```
dos2unix script.sh
```

to get rid of those pesky \r characters that windows put in.

Comment: It's a Linux server I'm connected to and executing the script on. I've created the file on a windows machine using Sublime and transfer it over to the server where I execute it. I'm not sure how to find the shell that I'm using, but hopefully that helps. Let me know if there's some command I can run to get that for you though

Comment: Files edited on a Windows computer end in \r\n, while files edited on Linux computers end in \n. This can cause your problem.

Comment: @Klox Sounds good. I'll give that a shot and get back to everyone

Answer (score -1):

VSCode users will find if they make a directory through vscode it will also contain that \r by default on macos (ksh terminal) or linux. All despite vscode running straight off the macos/linux system.